# combine insert with same table td value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Looping an object to generate the html table but needs to be in the same row if the value from the first key is the same.

initial html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myRequestsTbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my script pseudo code:

```
var startup = [{"id": "1","name": "foo"},{"id": "1","name": "dum"},{"id": "2","name": "testA"},{"id":"3","name": "testB"}]

var row = ""
Object.keys(startup) 
    .forEach(function eachKey(key) {

    row += '<tr><td>' + startup[key]['id']
            + '</td><td>' + startup[key]['name']
            + '</td></tr>';
   });

$('#myRequestsTbody').html(row);
```

and this output is something like this

```
+------+---------+
|  ID  |   Name  |
+------+---------+
|  1   |   foo   |
------------------
|  1   |   dum   |
------------------
|  2   |  testA  |
------------------
|  3   |  testB  |
+------+---------+
```

But what I exactly trying to display is something like this:

```
    +------+---------+
    |  ID  |   Name  |
    +------+---------+
    |  1       foo   |
    |          dum   |
    ------------------
    |  2   |  testA  |
    ------------------
    |  3   |  testB  |
    +------+---------+
```

The column name will be merge on a single row if the column id is in the same value

Any suggestions/comments TIA

Comment: Then first group them by id (you will find a solution for that here on SO) and then convert that into table rows.

Comment: Grouping first would be cleanest.  If you don't want to/can't do that then in your `.forEach` look for a matching row first, but you'll need to add to the DOM to use DOM finding methods (which will be less efficient).  You could build an array of html tr's key'd by id.

Comment: off topic: Anonymous functions can be... well.. anonymous `.forEach(function eachKey(key) {` should be `.forEach(function(key) {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group array elements by arbitrary set of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994129/how-to-group-array-elements-by-arbitrary-set-of-keys)

Answer (score 3):

First, please check the script in the code below. The full text of the code that will solve your problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myRequestsTbody"></tbody>
</table>

<script>
var startup = [{"id": "1","name": "foo"},{"id": "1","name": "dum"},{"id": "2","name": "testA"},{"id":"3","name": "testB"}];

var row = [...( new Set(startup.map(arr => arr.id)) )]
      .map( id => {
          var names = startup.filter(arr => arr.id === id).map(arr => arr.name).join("<br />")
          return `<tr><td>${id}</td><td>${names}</td></tr>`
      }).join("\n")
$("#myRequestsTbody").html(row)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above has some modern syntax that is difficult to understand. It is perfectly normal to get confused about this, and understanding these will help you write concise and powerful code.

Let's start with the first code line.

> [...( new Set(startup.map(arr => arr.id)) )]

This line of code extracts the key values from your presented array without duplicates.

### Explanation:

1. `() => {}` is a concise expression of a function. The left side of the arrow is the argument and the right side is the return value.
2. `startup.map(arr => arr.id)` It extracts only the id value from the array you provide. For more information on how to use the Array.map method, please refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
3. `[...( new Set( Array )) )]` This line of code eliminates all duplicate values. Set is an array-like object with no duplicate values, and we use the spread operator to convert it back to an array.

> var names = startup.filter(arr => arr.id === id).map(arr => arr.name).join("
> ")

Gets all names corresponding to the key values of the current loop.

### Explanation:

1. `.filter(arr => arr.id === id)` Gets the data object with the same id value as the current loop id value from the first array.
2. `.map(arr => arr.name)` Extracts only the name from the imported data object.
3. `.join("<br />")` is the action of adding a line break html tag between imported names.

The resulting `<tr><td>${id}</td><td>${names}</td></tr>` code wraps the id and names variables with html tags.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO answers.  This is a great solution - to make it a great answer, please add some explanation - even if it's relatively simple such as the terminology for the array reduction and what map does.     This might be of interest: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: Sorry for not taking the position of the person using the code. I will add the code description in the near future.

Comment: This might help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the simplest solution will be to group the data and then convert it into a table.

```js
const startup = [{"id": "1","name": "foo"},{"id": "1","name": "dum"},{"id": "2","name": "testA"},{"id":"3","name": "testB"}]


const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

const groubedByID = groupBy(startup, 'id');

const tbody = document.querySelector('#myRequestsTbody');
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();

for(const id in groubedByID) {
  const trow = document.createElement('tr');
  const tid = document.createElement('td');
  tid.innerHTML = id;
  const tname = document.createElement('td');
  groubedByID[id].forEach(d => {
    const nameDiv = document.createElement('div');
    nameDiv.innerHTML = d['name'];
    tname.appendChild(nameDiv);
  })
  trow.appendChild(tid);
  trow.appendChild(tname);
  fragment.appendChild(trow);
}

tbody.appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
table td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myRequestsTbody"></tbody>
</table>
```